# how to add a value to the fb post xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im creating a game an want to be able to add there score so when they post it on fb it shows them there high score, (to add a bit more of a social aspect as)

here is the code i am suing but it dosnt seem to work and crashes the app,

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
    [defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    [defaults synchronize];
    [self postwall];

}
- (void)postwall
{
    NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   //kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Watch Ma Balls", @"name",
                                   @"How long can you keep out of the way of ma balls for", @"caption",
                                   @"I reached a score of i% can you beat me!.",highscore, @"description",
                                   nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
}
```

the code works fine with out the

> highscore

there

is there a way that it can be added to the string so it shows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this (assuming `highscore` is an `int`):

```
NSString *string = @"I reached a score of ";
string = [string stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highscore]];
string = [string stringByAppendingString:@" can you beat me?"];

NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   //kAppId, @"app_id",
                                   @"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/", @"link",
                                   @"http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg", @"picture",
                                   @"Watch Ma Balls", @"name",
                                   @"How long can you keep out of the way of ma balls for", @"caption",
                                   string, @"description",
                                   nil];
```

Comment: Boom Perfect! i was kinda thinking of a similar idea just couldn't work it out so cheers buddy